# Delta-Wye for voltage sources?

Tags: voltage, network, voltage-source, y-to-delta, delta-to-y

My question is if, and how I can find an **equivalent network**, which includes **resistors and voltage sources** in series with arbitrary voltages and resistances, **so that to the outside the networks are equivalent**.

[image: Delta-Wye including voltage sources]

I understand that on top of the current flowing through the network, there will also be **internal currents in the Delta network**, which **will not be in the wye network**, however those **do not matter to me**.

All that is **important is that the potentials between each node will be equivalent to the outside.**

From doing something similar with **parallel configuration** of a voltage source with a resistor, I have found out that **it's basically a voltage divider to the outside**, and I thought **if the same logic could be applied** to this "3-way parallel" or "3-way series"

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried for D-Y conversion, adding up the adjacent voltages, to that  V1 = Vb+Vc, however that produced incorrect results.
I wasn't surprised, since this way I could produce higher potential than originally possible.
Nothing beyond that, as I don't understand electrical engineering well enough to wrap my head around it.